# Getting garbage values from iStochastic function MQL5

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

Here is the code and the output of the Strategy Tester:

```
void OnInit()
{
    double K[],D[];

    int s  = iStochastic(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1,5,3,3,MODE_SMA,STO_LOWHIGH);
    ArraySetAsSeries(K,true);
    CopyBuffer(s,0,0,15,K);
    for (int i=0; i< ArraySize(K); i++) {
        PrintFormat("K%d:  %f",i,K[i]);
    }
}
```

The output is here:

```
2018.03.23 17:52:23.771 EURUSD,M1: testing of Experts\testing lines and trdae.ex5 from 2018.02.01 00:00 to 2018.02.20 00:00 started
2018.03.23 17:52:23.821 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K0:  0.000000
2018.03.23 17:52:23.821 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K1:  0.000000
2018.03.23 17:52:23.821 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K2:  0.000000
2018.03.23 17:52:23.821 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K3:  0.000000
2018.03.23 17:52:23.821 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K4:  0.000000
2018.03.23 17:52:23.821 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K5:  0.000000
2018.03.23 17:52:23.821 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K6:  0.000000
2018.03.23 17:52:23.821 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K7:  0.000000
2018.03.23 17:52:23.821 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K8:  0.000000
2018.03.23 17:52:23.821 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K9:  0.000000
2018.03.23 17:52:23.821 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K10:  -199836181689466826799237394770318879446132938967474237529901448300177121542331695157382317059237724271211152856484244886720180840440527383821209628107006660663428982847878694191497216.000000
2018.03.23 17:52:23.821 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K11:  0.000000
2018.03.23 17:52:23.821 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K12:  0.000000
2018.03.23 17:52:23.821 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K13:  0.000000
2018.03.23 17:52:23.821 2018.02.01 00:00:00   K14:  0.000000
```

Previously I was getting correct values but now the values are all garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is nothing coming into your `K[]` and `D[]`. Hence you are facing the garbage value. And you are not willing to go with `OnTick()` instead want to implement with `OnInit()`, then I guess I can try something and you may debug it.

```
void OnInit()
{
    double K[],D[];

    int s  = iStochastic(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1,5,3,3,MODE_SMA,STO_LOWHIGH);
    ArraySetAsSeries(K,true);
    int KBuffer = CopyBuffer(s,0,0,15,K);
    if(KBuffer == -1)
   {
   Sleep(50);
   s  = iStochastic(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1,5,3,3,MODE_SMA,STO_LOWHIGH);
   CopyBuffer(s,0,0,15,K);
   }
    for (int i=0; i< ArraySize(K); i++) {
        PrintFormat("K%d:  %f",i,K[i]);
    }
}
```

I guess this is it. If you get the garbage again try increasing the `Sleep()` milliseconds.

Comment: Let me try it. I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You requested the stochastic indicator to run in `OnInit()` function, it is possible that stochastic is not loaded yet, or chart is not recognized. Try in `OnTick()` function. Also try to make sure that your handle is not `INVALID_HANDLE` and that you copied 15 elements succesfully (but I do not think that is a problem). It is quite important in MQL5 to make sure that all you did is finished!

Comment: I tried it using` OnTick()` but I came across same result :( sadly.

Comment: If I want to access the Stochastic values using `OnInit()` is it possible?